# invoking lambda from other lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

In our system we have a flow of Lambdas calling other Lambdas based on results they get.
This flow will probably be refactor to use the AWS step function in the future but will probably stay as it is for the next month or two.

Recently a new lambda has been introduced, and we're encountering a problem:

if we test our Lambda function 1 locally, it properly calls function 2 on AWS.

However, after deploying the lambda and running the same test, function doesn't get called (there's no invocation in the monitoring chart)

here's a code example of Function 1:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: "eu-west-1" });

const myHandler = async (event, _, callback) =>  {
  console.log(event)

  return doSomething()
            .then(something)
            .then(somethingElse)
            .catch(handleError)

 
function doSomething() {
     return fetch('someurl.com');
}


function something(r) {
   if(r.status === 204) {
      let lambdaRes = callLambda( "LambdaB",  { foo: bar } );
      console.log(lambdaRes)
   }
   return r
}


somethingElse(r) {
   if(r.status === 500) {
       throw new Error(`bar`);
   }
   return r.json()
}

async function callLambda(fnName, payload ) {
    let params = {
      FunctionName: fnName,
      InvocationType: 'Event',
      Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }
    return await lambda.invoke(params);
}

function handleError(e) {
    if(e.message === 'bar') {
       let lambdaRes = callLambda( "LambdaC",  { bar: 'foo' } );
       console.log(lambdaRes)
    }
    return callback(null, { message: `Completed with error`});
}


exports.handler = myHandler;
```

We tried to check if the problem was caused by authorization and tested by providing ALL authorization possible to function 1 but with no results.

Any suggestion?

UPDATE:

Both Function use the same

VPC: vpc-hashnumberVpc,
Subnets: [ subnet-hashnumber1 , subnet-hashnumber2 , subnet-hashnumber3 ]
Security Group: sg-hashnumberSg

Comment: You should really do a little more debugging to see what the logs from the first Lambda function look like. It's probably timing out on the `lambda.invoke()` line? If the first function isn't showing any errors at all, then you are not catching the error properly. You should also be capturing the output from `lambda.invoke()` and logging it.

Comment: Do you actually need the Lambda in your VPC? Are you interfacing to private services inside the VPC?

Comment: @MarkB it's not timing out, lambda moves further.
I tried to add a .then (console.log).catch(console.log) and there s no output

Comment: I see you're mixing `async` and `promises`. Why aren't you doing an `await`?

Comment: I think i tried once, gonna deploy the following:
let devManagerRes = await lambda.invoke(i)
console.log(devManager)

and see the result on the log

Comment: from the log

`[date] [idrequest]  INFO calling lambda C` 
`[<date] [idrequest]  INFO Promise { <pending> } `  
`[date] [idrequest]   Execution Completed `


first log is before call, second log is the result of calling, third log happens after some other DB access and manipulation

Comment: "Promise { <pending> } " means the promise hasn't completed and you aren't awaiting the promise. Until you have code that waits for the promise to complete, you don't know if it is throwing an error or timing out. I think your Lambda function is actually exiting before the promise completes.

Comment: here's the thing. The Lambda C doesn't show any invocation on his monitor section. Also, it gets called if i run the code above from my local environment, and properly works. 
Bts, it is intendeed to not wait for LAMBDA C to return. The idea is just to call it, LAMBDA C will run his own code and doesn t need to return anything to LAMBDA B

Comment: sorry, you mentioned step functions, so I will allow myself to add that you could look in to the fan out pattern? if the pass messages it seams that you could uses ques and sns?

Answer (score 1):

When the first Lambda function calls `lambda.invoke()` it is not somehow connecting to the other Lambda function inside the VPC. At that point there is no running instance of the other Lambda function, only the definition of it exists. What is happening is `lambda.invoke()` makes a call to the AWS API which is on the public Internet, requesting that AWS create a new invocation of the second function.

Lambda functions running inside a VPC do not get public IP addresses assigned to them, even if they are in a public subnet. The only way to give a Lambda function inside a VPC access to the Internet is to place the Lambda function in a private subnet with a route to a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).

Alternatively, you can configure an [AWS Lambda VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc-endpoints.html), which gives resources inside your VPC access to call the AWS Lambda API without going over the Internet.

So in order for a Lambda function running inside a VPC to make AWS API calls to invoke other Lambda functions, your options are to add a NAT Gateway to the VPC, or add an AWS Lambda VPC Endpoint to the VPC.

Comment: the flow is actually more complex. 
we have a lambda A that fetch items from DB, and from each item calls lambda B.
This part works and we have N calls for Lambda B.
Lambda B does some more manipulation and in certain case calls Lambda C or Lambda D.  

If i run Lambda B from local, Lambda C get called.  if i run Lambda B on AWS, LAmbda C doesn t get Called

Comment: That's good to know, but none of that changes the way AWS networking works. You need to add more logging in the Lambda B function code, including logging the response from the `lambda.invoke()` method.

Comment: I tried to do that, but there is no response, I'm gonna do it again, and update the question with the code

Comment: I've modified the function on the initial post to reflect our logic, this should clarify the flow

Answer (score -1):

So if function 1 is able to call function 2 locally, I think the problem is with networking/AWS setup, here are a few things you can do :

1. Set up Log/Print statements at every level, so you can pinpoint which line is returning an error.
2. Is the function timing out? If so check the timeout and **Memory Allocated** to the function, if the function is memory intensive it will not complete.
3. Last but very important , check your network/**Subnets**, if you have configured lambda to be running on multiple subnets, choose one of them and try, look at the **VPC**, perhaps the Lambda is not attached to any VPC or check if the attached vpc is able to connect to the other lambda, have a look at **Security Groups** as well.

Most of my lambda issues are resolved with this, all the best.

Comment: for point 1 and point 2 I can ensure the functions one works top top bottom (it's more complex than the given example). It complete others tasks after calling the lambda.

I'm gonna check the subnets now, for sure they are both on the same VPC.
Thanks for the hindsight

Comment: they are on the same VPC, use the same 3 Subnets, and the same security group :|

Comment: No that's not it, are they internet facing VPC?  Do they have connectivity to the internet? or can you simply call any aws service in the same VPC from Lambda 1? 
Also what specific error are you getting? hard to debug with no errors
Also please don't share VPC or security group IDs

Comment: They are facing internet yes, this allow me to run the Code from Function 1 locally to run  function 2 on AWS.

There's no error at all, the difference is that when running function 1 locally, I can see the invokation on function 2 on AWS, and check the output log.
However, if I deploy Function 1 and run a test on AWS, i can see Function 1 working as expected (from the log) but Function 2 doesn t get invoked (no log nor invokation on the dashboard)

Comment: In the response code from the log of Lambda Function 1 you should see an event ID, or an invocation ID, check cloudwatch to see what is happening to the invocation and/or trace it. Another solution would be to publish an SNS message instead of triggering the function directly and set a trigger at Lambda 2 from that same SNS topic but that's a workaround